# Passing parameter between views in MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC web app. I have a `searchString` parameter in the `Index` method. When parameter is filled, I can see value on web link, for example `...?SearchString=202`.

I'd like to send this parameter to the second method (for example `Edit`), not to change it there and send back to the `Index` method after user press the Back button.
The idea is that when the user press the Back button, he returns to the `Index` view but he lost `searchString` parameter and the user does not have a filtered page according to the previous search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass the searchString in the path of Index-Edit-Index , you could use `ViewBag` and then pass it as the routevalue.Refer to the following is a simple working demo :

*Index action*, save the searchString in `ViewBag.SearchString`.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString)
{
  var movies = from m in _context.Movie
             select m;

  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
  {
    movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
    ViewBag.SearchString = searchString;
  }

  return View(await movies.ToListAsync());
}
```

*Index View* , add the routevalue `returnString` in the Edit link

```
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id" asp-route-returnString="@ViewBag.SearchString">Edit</a>
```

*Edit action*

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id,string returnString = null)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var movie = await _context.Movie.FindAsync(id);

        ViewBag.SearchString = returnString;

        if (movie == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(movie);
    }
```

*Edit View* ,  Back link

```
<div>
@if (ViewBag.SearchString != null)
{
    <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-searchString="@ViewBag.SearchString">Back to List</a>
}
else
{
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
}
</div>
```

Comment: I wasn't expecting such a clean code. I like learning the correct code writing procedures. Thank you very much for your answer.